# Play2 server to server communication

Tags: sockets, scala, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.2

How can I implement server to server communication in play framework?

I have to send a lot of data, very frequently, I'm looking for something like websockets but between servers.
I could use simple socket, but my data is JSON. Is there any wrapper for sockets to use in similar way to websockets?

I'm using play 2.2 and scala.

Comment: What sort of servers are those?

Comment: They are serving JSON data for some HTTP(JSON) requests. You can connect to server by websockets to fetch a lot of data, and this data are on another play server, thats why I have implement communication between them. This is kind of stream (very frequent) JSON data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about Akka remoting? The actor model would fit well with the Play architecture, and would be a good way to handle unsolicited messages at the receiving end.

Comment: Akka remoting looks very nice, but how about performance comparing to JSON to string deserialization and sending by simple sockets? I have to send this data very frequently for example 100 JSON/s in one connection, and I could have multiple connections.

Comment: I don't think Akka overhead would be much, but the point of Akka is more about scalability. Based on your other comment, maybe a distributed cache (e.g. EHCache) would fit your requirement

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use ZeroMQ implementation in Akka [link](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.2/scala/zeromq.html). It is fine alternative to remote solution. The only drawback is that it depends on ZeroMQ native so you have to have ZeroMQ library installed. But it works great. Especially that you don't have to implement yourself Pub-Sub pattern.